# Android app widget listview item on click not highlighting

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

I am creating a app widget with a list view. when i click on the list view item it is not highlighting. Please help.

The scenario here is, when i click on the list view item, certain action buttons are shown at the bottom of the widget. but since the item is not highlighting, the user will not know which item is selected.

Provider.java

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        // initializing widget layout
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_4_4_layout);

            Intent listIntent = new Intent(context,
                    Widget_4_4_Service.class);
            listIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    appWidgetId);
            listIntent.putExtra("dur", String.valueOf(duration));
            listIntent.setData(Uri.parse(listIntent
                    .toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.id_widget_task_list,
                    listIntent);

            Intent taskIntent = new Intent(context,
                    Widget_4_4_Provider.class);
            taskIntent.setAction("action");

            PendingIntent taskPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    context, 3, taskIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.id_widget_task_list,
                    taskPendingIntent);

            }
}
```

Factory.java

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int pos) {
    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.custom_widget_list_view);
    TaskDO task = taskList.get(pos);
    remoteView
            .setTextViewText(R.id.id_widget_list_task_name, task.TaskName);

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("task", String.valueOf(task.TaskId));
    remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.id_widget_list_task_name, i);

    return remoteView;
}
```